# How do I revert a commit that I forgot to squash in git?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally merged a Pull Request when what I really meant to do was a squash and merge. As a result, my commit history now contains the ~20 individual commits from that PR.

**My goal is twofold**:

1. Revert back to the last "good" commit
2. Clear the "bad" commits from my commit history

*Most of these "bad" commits appear AFTER the last "good" commit, **but a handful of them appear BEFORE the last "good" commit (I'm guessing this is due to their commit dates), which I'm afraid complicates things for me.***

Fortunately, there haven't been any additional commits since this mistake was made.

Based on my research thus far, I can revert back to the last "good" commit by doing the following:

```
git reset --hard <commit-before-the-merge>
```

But given that the "bad" commits appear both before AND after the last "good" commit, I'm uncertain this will resolve the issue, and I don't want to try it without being reasonably confident it will work.

Will the command noted above do the trick, or should I be using a different set of commands to get myself out of this mess?

Comment: the "bad"  commits should not be part of the history of the "good" commit. You can confirm this : run `git log --oneline --graph` after your `git reset --hard ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before-or-after time-wise, i.e. older-or-newer, shouldn't matter. What matters to Git is the *ancestry* of commits, which is purely defined through the `parent:` line in each commit object.

Use git log to check if any invalid commits would be reset:

```
git log $last_good_commit..$bad_commit
```

But even if it contains commits which you want to keep, you can always use `git cherry-pick` to create a new commit with the same patch.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, To undo something i usually use git reflog, for insance. undo git merge or git rebase; I will back to the time before that command with sha1 hash in git reflog.